# How to create a simple program that creates a public link for Google Drive, like Dropbox?

Tags: windows, operating-system, google-drive-api

My question question/vision for this is to create a "public link" from a right click inside of my Google Drive folder, just like you would with Dropbox. We are closer to achieving this because Google Drive now has site publishing. See this post for more information: **http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/11/announcing-google-drive-site-publishing.html**

That means we can create a public folder inside of Google Drive, such as: **https://googledrive.com/host/[public-folder-random-string]/[filename]**

I was wondering if there was a way to add a Windows right click option that will automatically show up when in the public folder on my computer and have it allow me to create a public link, by automatically filling in the URL, the random string, and then adding the subfolder/filename after the public folder URL, then making that "pasteable".

Here is an example of how Dropbox feature like this works: **http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxclGfUBJqg**

I am not a computer programmer and have no knowledge on how to create something like this, just wondering if this community could make this happen or help me find someone who can.

I look forward to hearing from everyone.

**EDIT:** Is this related to C++ or programming related to that nature?